# Converting data from EntityFramework to C# object-codes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've got a complex structure of data from a SQL by using EntityFramework (v5). 
For example:

```
class user {
   int Id {get;set}
   string Name {get;set;}
   Group Group {get;set;}
   int GroupId {get;set;}
}
class Group {
   int Id {get;set;}
   string Name {get;set;}
   ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

In my SQL-database we've create a bunch of objects as 'Preperation-Data'. I would like to convert this data from the SQL to C# code.

Input (Colums Seperated for reading purposes):
Users

```
Id   Name   GroupId
1    First  1
2    Second 1
3    Third  2
```

Groups

```
Id   Name  
1    FirstGroup
2    SecondGroup
```

The output I would like to have:

```
new User() {Id = 1, Name = First, GroupId = 1};
new User() {Id = 2, Name = Second, GroupId = 1};
new User() {Id = 3, Name = Third, GroupId = 2};
new Group() {Id = 1, Name = FirstGroup};
new Group() {Id = 2, Name = FirstGroup};
```

Like I previously said I've got a very complex structure of data so the example above is very simplified.

Are there any tools/codesets available to create this situation?\

Thank you in advance for a reaction!

Comment: do you want to convert SQL to c#? If you have the SQL Code, why don't execute it?. Then, you can retrieve the data using entity framework

Comment: @FabioLuz I have the SQL-data and need to convert it to c# code. I don't want to execute it to any database.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but are you trying to reverse engineer SQL schema into Entity Framework POCO classes and model code? If so, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

Comment: @SteveGreene I hoped I made it clear in my question. I have a database filled with data. I created models with EF (databasefirst/edmx). Now I want the data in the database to be converted to c# code (not objects but real code like descriped in my question).

Comment: You could use a T4 template to do that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396